Hotspot connection in Ubuntu 24.04.01 not working with Android 12 phone
If activating the Hotspot in the GUI of Ubuntu 24.04.01 (freshly installed) I see the QRcode, can scan it with the Phone but any connection fails.
The wifi adapter itself seems to work as I can connect to a local wifi network. That same Laptop with the same wifi adapter worked perfectly with the Android phone on Ubuntu 18.04 before.
I also tried following an answer for a question on a similar issue and chased for a Hotspot file located in

/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections

but in my case that folder is empty (no hidden files).
Any idea why the Hotspot isn't working?
